# Is a character within a characterset? validation for a Webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, character-encoding

Currently I want to implement a characterset validation in the next way:

1. The (XML) message is sent to the webservice with a give characterset or with none.
2. Webservice gets the message and stores it in a String, which is UTF-16 and won't make any changes to any character.
3. Make another String giving it the character set initially given when the message was sent. Let's say ISO-8859-1.
4. Compare the two string. If they're equal: message didn't have any character that doesn't exist within the characterset. If not equal: in this case because of let's say a euro sign **'€'** was in the original message, then give an exception.

**My question: are there better ways to do this?**

Comment: with the validation you've described, you'd effectively be limiting your code to use 7-bit ascii characters only. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CharsetEncoder e=Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder();
// tell that we want an exception
e.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
// this will pass
e.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("hello iso latin 1"));
// this will throw
e.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("\u20ac is a non-latin-1 character"));
```

or

```
CharsetEncoder e=Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder();
// this will pass
if(!e.canEncode("hello iso latin 1"))
  throw new CharacterCodingException();
// this will throw
if(!e.canEncode("\u20ac is a non-latin-1 character"))
  throw new CharacterCodingException();
```

But you should ask yourself why you need this. XML files can represent any unicode character using the `&#…;` entities. Let the XML library handle this.

Comment: Hi Holger, nice solution. Just tested your second one and it works.

Comment: Regarding your comment about XML being able to represent any unicode character. I'm actually trying to prevent a user from sending a message with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> and using a euro sign €. Currently this would results in '?' being written to the database.

Comment: But this should not depend on the XML encoding (as said, XML can contain any unicode character anyway) but the encoding your database uses. Or you are running into the old problem that browsers claim to send `ISO-8859-1` but actually send `Windows-1252`

Comment: Actually we've discussed about the database encoding, which is set on ISO-8859-1. I'm new in the organization so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. The data is sent by custom software towards a webservice. It's not sent from a browser.